# regular expressions : (.*), (.*?) and .*

Tags: python, regex

Could someone explain to me the difference between these 3 blocks:

```
1 -> (.*)
2 -> (.*?)
3 -> .*
```

As I understand, `?` makes the last character optional so why put it `?` And why not put the parenthesis at the end?

This comes from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

```
1st example : searchObj = re.search( r'(.*) are (.*?) .*', line, re.M|re.I)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.*` will match any character (including newlines if dotall is used). This is greedy: it matches as much as it can.

`(.*)` will add that to a capture group.

`(.*?)` the `?` makes the `.*` non-greedy, matching as little as it can to make a match, and the parenthesis makes it a capture group as well.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = ''' foo
... bar
... baz '''
>>> for found in re.finditer('(.*)', txt):
...     print found.groups()
... 
(' foo',)
('',)
('bar',)
('',)
('baz ',)
('',)
>>> for found in re.finditer('.*', txt):
...     print found.groups()
... 
()
()
()
()
()
()
>>> for found in re.finditer('.*', txt, re.DOTALL):
...     print found.groups()
... 
()
()
>>> for found in re.finditer('(.*)', txt, re.DOTALL):
...     print found.groups()
... 
(' foo\nbar\nbaz ',)
('',)
```

And since the `?` matches as little as possible, we match empty strings:

```
>>> for found in re.finditer('(.*?)', txt, re.DOTALL):
...     print found.groups()
... 
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
('',)
```

Comment: An example: matching `(.*)h` against `"this thing"` returns `"this t"` (the longest possible string ending in h); matching `(.*?)h` would return `"t"` instead (the shortest possible string ending in h).

Comment: Well thank you all, very interesting links too. As I understand now that english natives define "greedy" as the one who takes a lot when the french natives define "greedy" as the one who gives back/returns the minimum. ;)